# why my shell script is printing the code as part of output

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash

haf()
{
 sshpass -p "$1" ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$2"@"$3" <<'SSH_EOF'

 echo "request msha actions status" | /opt/tel/vs/ns/current/bin/ns_cli > txt1
 tr -s " " < txt1 > txt2
 cut -d " " -f 2 txt2 > txt3
 var1=$(<txt3)

 if [ "$var1" = "MASTER" ]
 then
        var2=1
 elif [ "$var1" = "SLAVE" ]
 then
        var2=2
 else
        var2=3
 fi
 echo $var2 > txt4
 rm txt1 txt2 txt3
 logout
SSH_EOF
 sshpass -p "$1" scp "$2"@"$3":~/txt4 .
 var2=$(<txt4)
 sshpass -p "$1" ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$2"@"$3" <<'SSH_EOF'
 rm txt4
 logout
SSH_EOF
 rm txt4
 return $var2
}

haf "$1" "$2" "$3"
FL1=$?
```

#### OUTPUT

```
admin@tel:~$

/vs/ns/current/bin/ns_cli > txt1 request msha actions status" | /opt/tel
admin@tel:~$  tr -s " " < txt1 > txt2
admin@tel:~$  cut -d " " -f 2 txt2 > txt3
admin@tel:~$  var1=$(<txt3)
admin@tel:~$
admin@tel:~$  if [ "$var1" = "MASTER" ]
>  then
> var2=1
>  elif [ "$var1" = "SLAVE" ]
>  then
>         var2=2
>  else
> var2=3
>  fi
admin@tel:~$  echo $var2 > txt4
admin@tel:~$  rm txt1 txt2 txt3
admin@tel:~$  logout
Connection to 192.168.66.39 closed.
admin@tel:~$  rm txt4
admin@tel:~$  logout
Connection to 192.168.66.39 closed.
FL1=1
```

Correct/desired output is **only** `FL1=1`, with nothing else.

I am running this script in Ubuntu 14.04.1

Comment: What command does the remote `ssh` run? `var1=$(<txt3)` is a bashimism, does the remove executes bash?

Comment: Pass `bash -s` as an explicit remote command if you want to guarantee that bash (specifically, not some random `/bin/sh`) runs as a remote, noninteractive shell and reads from stdin. That is: `ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$2@$3" 'bash -s' <<'SSH_EOF'`

Comment: I'd also generally suggest against forcing a remote TTY unless you have an explicit, compelling reason to do so. Passing `-tt` can make remote programs act like they're receiving human input, whereas here the input is intentionally programmatic instead. (That's part of why you're getting a prompt printed at all!)

Comment: BTW, it's important to distinguish between *stdout* and *stderr*. Prompts, connected/disconnected messages, etc. are printed to stderr, not stdout; they're informational logging, not output.

Comment: sreekanth@versa-ftp:~$ ./hh.sh 'cryPT0log!c'  2222  admin 192.168.126.163
 
@CharlesDuffy even after adding 'bash -s' I am still seeing the code as output

Comment: @KamilCuk, Sorry I did not understand what you are asking.

Comment: Have you taken out the `-tt`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy looks like by removing -tt code is not printing to my screen. I will reverify it and update you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank You Charles its working!

Comment: Glad to help. By the way, be careful with `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` -- you give up a lot of the security benefits of ssh when you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the `-tt` arguments to ssh, and *don't* pass any explicit remote command to run, that results in an interactive shell being run on the remote side.

Interactive shells print prompts, and they echo the commands a user is running back to that user.

So, there are two things -- either one should fix this problem, but it's better to do both:

- Stop using `-tt` unless you have a specific, compelling reason to use it.
- Pass `bash -s` as the explicit remote command to run. (This also guarantees that the remote shell is bash, not `/bin/sh`, and thus that bash-only syntax will work).